# PHP: Reading remote file using fread, chunk size keeps varying

Tags: php, fread

I am using the following sort of function to read remote files

```
define('BUFSIZ', 4095);
$url = "file url";
$rfile = fopen($url, 'r');
$lfile = fopen(basename($url), 'w');
while(!feof($rfile))
fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ), BUFSIZ);
fclose($rfile); 
fclose($lfile);
```

but fread reads the file with chunksizes like 2kb, 3kb , 7kb etc and not the specified chunksize

i searched for hours but wasn't able to figure out the issue.

I am actually trying to download a remote file and upload it , the files are big which is creating memory issues on the server thus i can't use file_get_contents.

Varying chunksize messes up the upload since the chunksize needs to pre defined before starting the upload.

----Edit----

> if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file,
>   at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size 
>   (usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the
>   size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size.

anyways to bypass this?

Or **how can i read data from remote files in chunks other than using fopen and fread?**

Answer (score 0):

I found that the PHP Engine has a Chunk Size of 8kB by default.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

> if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file,
>   at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size
>   (usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the
>   size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size.

in the sample code `BUFSIZ` can only be lesser than the internal default Chunk Size.

```
fread($rfile, BUFSIZ);
```

But still the actual amount of Data read depends on the Network Bandwidth if you read from a Remote Source.

You can see this when you monitor your script with `strace` on Linux:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("<remote.ip>")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 3000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)               = 0
sendto(3, "GET /remote_file.txt HTTP"..., 181, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 181
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 3000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Mon, 15 M"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 4320
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 3000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "\362F\334\350h\t\350 \211R\200\272\312}\320Ftn~\240\350\32k\177\265\333\\\257\222\345?\203"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 8192
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "\350", 1, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL) = 1
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 3000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "\350\260r\205D\5\343\377\323\357\306B6\335|\213OM\205\237i\236\306\356(\304-\214F\305=>"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 1834
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 3000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "/\26\v\f\250!(\2\22\342\250\235i\fKQe\2058\322\275\315:\270f\266\24R\326bn\371"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 1440
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
```

We see that the first downloaded Chunk only does have 4kB and only the second one really fills up with 8kB but subsequent Chunks only fill up with less than 2 kb

The Bandwidth does limit the Download in this case.
The same will happen with the Upload.

You can change the Chunk Size of the Connection with the PHP Function `stream_set_chunk_size()`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-chunk-size.php

```
$rfile = fopen($url, 'r');
$lfile = fopen(basename($url), 'w');
stream_set_chunk_size($rfile, BUFSIZ);
stream_set_chunk_size($lfile, BUFSIZ);
```

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php states that

```
if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file, 
at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size 
(usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the 
size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size.
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> i searched for hours

... in all the wrong places it seems

EDIT: as a side note - where is the question ?

Comment: i did come across that too but didn't really understand that, why does the chunksize depend on the previously buffered data? no way to bypass that? :/

Comment: you may want to look at php streams - though I never used them